# Improving performance of counts in a subquery with millions of rows using Prefetch

Tags: django, postgresql

I have an application that monitors events from websites and part of the user interface shows counts of events per website for a given period of time. Here are what the models look like:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    url = models.TextField()

class Event(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, related_name="events")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

These websites generate thousands of events per day, so the `Event` table is quite large compared to the other tables. Here is what the query looks like that I'm trying to generate:

```
eargs = {
    "website": OuterRef("pk"),
    "created_at__gte": some_start_time,
    "created_at__lt": some_end_time
}
events = Event.objects.filter(**eargs).values("website")
events_count = events.annotate(c=Count("*").values("c")[:1]

websites = Website.objects.annotate(events=Coalesce(Subquery(events_count,
                                                    output_field=IntegerField()), 0)
```

Like I mentioned before, the `Events` table has millions of rows in it. For a small number of websites, this query doesn't take too long. But when there are 100 or more website, it takes quite a long time. I've done some profiling and the database (internally) is querying for the count for every website. So if I have 100 websites, the database is making 100 queries to generate the counts (there is still one query coming from Django, but Postgres, internally, is making those 100s of subqueries).

What I'd like to be able to do is prefetch those counts, because when I run the following raw SQL it's actually quite fast:

```
SELECT
    website_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    myapp_events
WHERE
    created_at >= some_start_time AND created_at < some_end_time
GROUP BY
    website_id;
```

Is there any possible way to prefetch that query and still use the results in my QuerySet? Or have I gone about this all wrong? This seems like it would be a common thing to do and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to speed it up.

Comment: For those that come across this in the future, I ended up writing a custom manager that calls `cursor.execute()` on a raw query. It is not ideal because I lose the nice filtering syntax of Django, but it has dramatically improved the performance. In the end, however, I have decided to push some of this to ElasticSearch instead.